# Inline SVG shrinks on IE11/10

Tags: html, css, svg

I have two great, responsive SVG's that I've exported from Illustrator. The SVG tag includes a viewBox and does not specify height/width-- those are being set through CSS. I'm using the SVG's inline.

Everything looks great EXCEPT in IE10/IE11. Every article I can find says with the viewbox and height/width attributes left out, SVG should scale on IE.

My SVG tag looks like:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 880 452" style="enable-background:new 0 0 880 452;" xml:space="preserve">
```

CSS:

```
svg {
  width: 100%;
}
```

BUT when I do add the height/width attributes, it does work on IE (despite all of the articles I'm reading). But now, it doesn't work on other browsers because it throws off the size of the SVG (it stays 400px height even on small screens).

I can't find ANY css fix that would help on IE, even declaring a set height/width on the SVG or any of it's components (even including !important) does not change the size of the SVG it remains about 150px width.

Can anyone help me what is going on here so that it looks somewhat normal on IE?

Comment: No, you don't want to leave out `viewbox`. https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

Comment: @cbroe I did not leave out the viewBox. It is there in the tag.

Comment: The padding-bottom hack should work.